# Union of 2 arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

**My code**

```
class Union {

    //Search Function
    static boolean search(int A[], int i) {

        for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
            if (A[k] == i) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //union
    static void union(int A[][], int B[][]) {

        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int C[] = new int[A.length + B.length];

        for (; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (!(search(B, A[i]))) {
                C[count] = A[i];
                count++;
            }
        }

        for (; i < (A.length + B.length); i++) {
            C[count] = B[i - A.length];
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("This is Union Of 2 D Array ");
        System.out.println();

        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
            System.out.println(C[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void main(String... s) {
        union(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 4,}, new int[]{1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2});
    }
}
```

I am using this output to find union of 2d array .but output which i am getting is wrong . i  don't want 2 use any predefined interface and method in java .
my answer should be 
{1,2,4}

**Example**

```
A= {1,2,3,3}
B={2,3,1,1}
c={1,2,3}
```

Comment: Your code appears to only have 1d arrays. Where are the 2d arrays?

Comment: if i am wrong in this code correct me

Comment: @Guarav_Java: It's hard to correct you when we don't know what you're looking for - but Peter is right, you *are* only using 1D arrays. Note that the idiomatic declaration of an array type variable is to keep all the type information together: `int[] x` rather than `int x[]`. Also, parameter names are conventionally camelCased.

Comment: A 2D array need two dimensions i.e. `union(int[][] a, int[][] b)` which is what makes it a 2D (two dimensional) array.

Comment: @Gaurav_Java Could you provide an example? Sample input and the expected output.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad added example

Comment: @Eng.Fouad. That what i call answer . thanks . please upvote my question someone downvote

Comment: @Gaurav_Java You are welcome. Don't forget to give me the bounty ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad. You have 2 wait for 7 hours system policy.;)

Comment: @Gaurav_Java no problem. I improved my answer with providing the counter to `isDuplicated()` method.

Comment: @Gaurav_Java I updated my answer with better implementation :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9524/discussion-between-gaurav-java-and-eng-fouad)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Union
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 3};
        int[] B = {2, 3, 1, 1};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unionArrays(A, B)));
    }

    /* Union of multiple arrays */
    public static int[] unionArrays(int[]... arrays)
    {
        int maxSize = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        for(int[] array : arrays) maxSize += array.length;
        int[] accumulator = new int[maxSize];

        for(int[] array : arrays)
            for(int i : array)
                if(!isDuplicated(accumulator, counter, i))
                    accumulator[counter++] = i;

        int[] result = new int[counter];
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) result[i] = accumulator[i];

        return result;
    }

    public static boolean isDuplicated(int[] array, int counter, int value)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) if(array[i] == value) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: int[] A = {4,5,6 };
  int[] B = { 1,2, 3,5, 1, 1 };  it fails for this input

Answer (score 8):

Not specifically answering your question, but if you actually just want to get a union, you should probably use the java [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface. See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Set is a natural choice when you want uniqueness. To avoid a lot of conversions, you can change from `int[]` to `Integer[]` and get a very short and clean union method.

Here's a complete working example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Union {
  // Search Function
  public boolean search(Integer a[], Integer i) {
    for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
      if(a[k] == i) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;               
  }

  // Union
  public void union(Integer[] a, Integer[] b) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));
    Integer[] unionArray = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unionArray));
  }

  public static void main(String...s) {
    Integer[] array1 = new Integer[]{1,1,1,4,};
    Integer[] array2 = new Integer[]{1,4,4,4,1,2};
    new Union().union(array1, array2);
  }
}
```

Obviously, there is overhead here to convert from array to list, then that list to set, then that set back to array. However, it's usually not worth having convoluted code that does something faster - only when you find out that you have a performance bottleneck in this part of the code it would be useful to go to a direct and longer (code-wise) solution.

Using Set also avoids a common mistake where you iterate through the array to search for the element to confirm that the element you are adding is not a duplicate. Commonly, solutions such as this have O(n^2) time complexity (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)).

This is not going to be an issue when your arrays have 10 elements, but if you have two arrays of, say, 1000 unique elements each, you are going to do a lot of unnecessary walking, making your code really slow. In this case, in an array-based solution with duplicate checking by walking through the array, you would have to perform 1000 * 1000 / 2 = 500K operations, while a set-based one will be close to 5k:

- 1000 to convert the first array to a list,
- 1000 to convert list to set,
- 1000 to convert the second array to a list,
- 1000 to add the second array to the set and
- 1000 to convert it back from the set an array)

as set-based solution is O(n). If you assume these operations are approximately the same (not true, but not a bad approximation nonetheless), this is 100 times faster.

Moreover, this increases fast with increasing the number of unique elements - for 10K elements in each of the arrays, array-based walking solution would take an order of 50,000,000 operations, while a set-based one would take an order of 15,000.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @icyrocks. Great Answer thanks this will help u . but i am restricted not to use these functions and predefined methods

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted is dealing with 1d arrays, not 2d =) Code seems to try join contents of two arrays into another array. For that, just do following:

```
public static int[] joinArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a == null || b == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both arrays must be non-null");
    int c[] = new int[a.length + b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: i want this to run without using System.arraycopy

Answer (score 1):

A = {1,1,1,4} B = { 1,4,4,4,1,2}

Mathematically  the union of set A and B would be C = {1,4,2}

or do you want repeatation such as , C = {1,1,1,1,1,2,4,4,4,4}

Which one is your expected output ? first one or the second one ?

```
public class Union_2{
static int size;

public static void main(String [] args){
int [] a = {1,1,1,4};
int [] b = {1,4,4,4,1,2};
int [] c = Union_finder(a,b);
for(int i = 0 ; i< size ; i++){
  System.out.print(c[i]+" ");
}
}
public static int[] Union_finder(int [] a,int [] b){
int [] c = new int[a.length+b.length];
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
for(;i<a.length;i++){
  boolean bool = check(a[i],c);
  if( bool == false){
    c[k] = a[i];
    size++;
    k++;
  }
}
for(;j<b.length;j++){
  boolean bool = check(b[j],c);
  if( bool== false){
    c[k] = b[j];
    size++;
    k++;
  }
}
return c ;
}
public static boolean check(int x,int [] c){
if(size == 0){
  return false;
}
else{
  for(int i = size - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if( c[i] == x){
      return true ;
    }
  }
}
return false ;
}
}
```

Comment: First output 
 this u post in answer can be done in comment also

Comment: I added the code u were looking for, it finds the union of two sets and displays the result, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

// I hope this example will simple one.
//pass two arrays and you will definitely get UNION of array without duplicate items.

```
public class UnionOfArrays 
{
```

`public int[] getUnion(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
{
    int[] array = MergeSort.mergeArray(arr1, arr2);
    int[] arrReturn = getunique(array);
    return arrReturn;
}   
public int[] getunique(int[] array)
{
    int[] arrTemp = new int[array.length];
    int[] arrReturn;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        Boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == array[j])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            arrTemp[index++] = array[i];
        }
    }
    arrReturn = new int[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        arrReturn[i] = arrTemp[i];
    }
    return arrReturn;
}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int[] arrayUnion(int a1[], int a2[]){
        int[] resultArray={};
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if(a1.length>a2.length){
            resultArray=new int[a1.length];
        }else resultArray=new int[a2.length];

        for(int element : a1){
            arrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(element));

        }
        for(int element:a2){
            if(! arrayList.contains(element)){
                arrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(element));
            }
        }

        resultArray = arrayList.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray(); // only in java 8
       return  resultArray;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list1);
    set.addAll(list2);
    List<String> union = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will simple one.pass two arrays and you will definitely get UNION of array without duplicate items.

```
private static int[] FindUnionOfTwoArray(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        Map<Integer,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
        for (int element : array1) {
            map.put(element, element);
        }
        for (int element : array2) {
            map.put(element, element);
        }
        int[] newArray=new int[map.size()];
        int con=0;
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> lst:map.entrySet()) {
            newArray[con]=lst.getValue();
            con++;
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int doUnion(int a[], int n, int b[], int m) 
{
        HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
          
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
            hs.add(a[i]);         
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)  
            hs.add(b[i]); 
        return hs.size();
}
```