# Union of Two Int Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, exception, union

This is my code

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
class union {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

int[] A = new int[1000];
int[] B = new int[1000];
int[] C = new int[2000];    
    for (int i= 3;i < 1000 ; i += 3) {
        A[i/3] = i; 
    }
    for (int j=5; j < 1000; j += 5) {
        B[j/5] = j;
    }

    C = unionArrays(A, B);

    }
}
```

I got the following error on Compiling

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method unionArrays(int[], int[]) is undefined for the type union

    at union.main(union.java:15)
```

Comment: Where is `unionArrays`.

Comment: Where is `unionArrays(int[], int[])` defined?

Comment: I guess you are using a function/method you learned in some other language. Read the java-docs. See what methods are exposed and are provided by that class.

Comment: There's no question here.  Closing as too localized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you would want to use a HashSet instead of an array like so:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class ProjectEulerOne{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 HashSet<Integer> SetA= new HashSet<Integer>();
  for(int i = 3; i<1000; i+=3){
     SetA.add(new Integer(i));
  }
  for(int i = 3; i<1000; i+=3){
     SetA.add(new Integer(i));
  }
  int total =0;
  Iterator<Integer> iter = numSet.iterator();
  Integer current;
  while(iter.hasnext()){
   current = iter.next();
   total += current.intValue();
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the [HashSet javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), I completed this because "iterators are weird", but good luck on the rest of your Project Euler.

If you want to do it the math way I reccomend using either APL / J / K which support list math.

Comment: It's asking to create the class <integer> as it is not defined.

Comment: It is Integer not integer, sorry edited main post

Answer (score 0):

Define `unionArrays(int[], int[])` in your class. Check similar [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818057/union-of-2-arrays-in-java).