# Angular 4 List filtering

Tags: angular

I have two lists as below. How to merge two lists with unique value (1), and how to exclude the second list items in the first list (2)

```
private List1: [];
private List2: [];
this.List1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
this.List2 = [2, 4, 6];
```

Results

```
1) result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

2) result = [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Union of 2 arrays in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818057/union-of-2-arrays-in-java) and Possible duplicate of [Java, find intersection of two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863319/java-find-intersection-of-two-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

1) For `unique` set you can work with `Set` object and give to it an array. `Set` will remove duplicates automatically.

2) For `excluded` array you can use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and using a condition inside it take those items which are not in the `list2`.

```js
const list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const list2 = [2, 4, 6];

const unique = [...new Set(list1.concat(list2))];
console.log(unique);

const excluded = list1.filter(item => !list2.includes(item));
console.log(excluded);
```